# Deleting from table

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to make it so the logged in user only can delete his own posts, but the user with id 1/ admin can delete all posts.
What am i doing wrong here?

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

$postitid = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pid', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) 
or die ('Missing or illegal id parameter');
$userid = $_SESSION['users_id'];

require_once('dbcon.php');

$mysqlstring = 'DELETE FROM postit WHERE id=? AND users_id=? OR 
users_id=1';
$stmt = $link->prepare($mysqlstring);
$stmt ->bind_param('iii', $postitid, $userid, $userid);
$stmt -> execute();

if ($postitid == $userid ) {
echo 'Deleted '.$stmt->affected_rows.' Post-it notes';
} else {
echo 'You dont have permission to delete this.';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `What am i doing wrong here?` what is the problem?

Comment: every time you delete posts with user's id and admin's id

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: "but the user with id 1/ admin can delete all posts." that would be normal right that a admin can always delete?

Comment: `if(userid != 1) delete ...WHERE id=? AND users_id=?  else delete ...WHERE id=? `

Comment: "but the user with id 1/ admin can delete all posts. What am i doing wrong here?" check the query.. WHERE id=? AND users_id=? **OR 
users_id=1**

Comment: Why three params when there are only two needed- $stmt ->bind_param('iii', $postitid, $userid, $userid); You have already hardcoded users_id=1 in your query which denotes the Admin. Another suggestion would be to frame your query like this - 'DELETE FROM postit WHERE id=? AND (users_id=? OR 
users_id=1)"; followed by $stmt ->bind_param('ii', $postitid, $userid);

Comment: Another point - Why - ($postitid == $userid )  -- How can PostId (id of post meant to be deleted) be compared with userid? Wouldn't that condition fail for all but one occasion where PostId and UserId are fated to be the same not by choice but by chance. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here

```
$mysqlstring = 'DELETE FROM postit WHERE id=? AND users_id=? OR users_id=1';
```

This query deletes the post that belongs to an admin(users_id=1) or logged user. You don't want that, you want to check if user is admin and let him delete given post with id, and if it's a user then he should only delete the post if he's an owner of it. To do so:

You need to check if user_id = 1 if so then make different query

```
 if (intval($userid) === 1) {
   // admin 
   $mysqlstring = 'DELETE FROM postit WHERE id=?';
   $stmt = $link->prepare($mysqlstring);
   $stmt ->bind_param('i', $postitid);
 } else {
   $mysqlstring = 'DELETE FROM postit WHERE id=? AND users_id=?';
   $stmt = $link->prepare($mysqlstring);
   $stmt ->bind_param('ii', $postitid, $userid);
 }

 $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

FIrst of all the mysqli string you are using

```
$mysqlstring = 'DELETE FROM postit WHERE id=? AND users_id=? OR users_id=1';
```

Since id in table is a primary key so you can use directly

```
$mysqlstring = 'DELETE FROM postit WHERE id=? ';
```

Or

```
$mysqlstring = 'DELETE FROM postit WHERE id=? AND (users_id=? OR users_id=1)';
```

or

```
$mysqlstring = 'DELETE FROM postit WHERE id=? AND users_id in (?,1)';
```